# Aliassing when flipping a texture in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I've created a multi-texture fragment shader in which I want to flip one of the textures but when doing this my texture gets all jaggy. Is there a solution to this problem?

[image: Jaggy borders]

This is my fragment shader code:

```
void main(void)
{
    lowp vec4 camera = texture2D(texture0, destinationTexCoord);
    lowp vec4 viewfinder = texture2D(texture1, vec2(destinationTexCoord.x, 1.0 - destinationTexCoord.y));

    lowp vec4 result = mix(camera, viewfinder, viewfinder.a);
    gl_FragColor = result;
}
```

Texture filtering I'm using:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Some background information: I'm blending these textures in my fragment shader (blending code stripped out) so I'm not looking for a solution where I rotate a second plane and merge them down on the framebuffer. I'm wondering if it is a good idea to flip/rotate around the texture coordinates in my fragment shader.

In the end I'll pass in a uniform saying: rotate or don't, resulting in that one texture getting rotated or not.

Comment: Did you forget to enable texture filtering for that texture?

Comment: Edited the initial post: I've added the texture filtering I'm using

Comment: Could you post a picture of what this looks like?

Comment: Wouldn't flipping the texture in vertex shader be faster, actually? Fragment shader is of course more powerful, but since you only need *per-vertex* flip of one coordinate, non some nonlinear manipulations...

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz does this also work if I want to rotate only 1 texture in my multi-texture shader?

Comment: Hmm. I see the problem. You could have two (or more) `varying` texture coordinates, of course, to compensate for that. Now if it will really be better/faster/(stronger ;)) than the fragment shader flip - you ought to test yourself.

Comment: I've added an image to the initial post for clarification.

Comment: Not only is the vertex shader the appropriate place for this semantically, but you're also introducing a dependent texture read!  My theory is that the precision of destinationTexCoord is too low.  Send a mediump vec2 over from the vert shader = problem solved.

Comment: Ok @Jessy I'll give that a try and will let you know i it works out.

Comment: @Jessy switching from lowp to mediump/highp for my texture coordinates solved the jaggyness. Can you make an answer of your comment, then I'll give you the rep you deserve. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mediump instead of lowp for destinationTexCoord will improve the sampling rate for
the vec2(destinationTexCoord.x, 1.0 - destinationTexCoord.y) calculation.  However, my recommendation is to use two varying vec2s instead of using a dependent texture read.  i.e. *cameraTexCoord* and *viewfinderTexCoord*.  You can avoid a mediump calculation in the fragment shader, and take advantage of the hardware's (hopefully) optimized vert-frag interpolation.

There's really no reason to use lowp for texture coordinates, unless they are dependent, in which case lowp may be better for the fragment shader calculations. Otherwise, lowp has not resulted in any gains, in my experience (I only know PowerVR hardware on iOS though).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the extra info about lowp. ;)